# injecting username as constructor parameter to repository using Ninject

Tags: .net, entity-framework, dependency-injection, ef-code-first, ninject

I found several questions using parameter passing to a constructor but i can't translate it to my specific problem.

I'm studying EF codefirst in combination with MVC.

I've created an abstract class and an interface as a base:

```
public abstract class RepositoryBase<C, T> : IRepositoryBase<T> 
    where T: class where C : DbContext,  new()

public interface IRepositoryBase<T> where T : class
```

for my model repositories iv'e created in concrete class with an interface

```
public interface ICustomerRepository : IRepositoryBase<Customer>

public class CustomerRepository: RepositoryBase<PNMP, Customer>,
    ICustomerRepository
```

the PNMP (my code first context) only has a constructor that accepts the user identity for tracking changes setting the internal parameter _username

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    var changeSet = ChangeTracker.Entries<IDatabaseBaseType>();

    if (changeSet != null)
    {
        var modifiedEntries =
            changeSet.Where(c => c.State== EntityState.Modified);

        foreach (var entry in modifiedEntries)
        {
            entry.Entity.ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;
            entry.Entity.ModifiedBy = _username;
        }

        var addedEntries =
            changeSet.Where(c => c.State == EntityState.Added);

        foreach (var entry in addedEntries)
        {
            entry.Entity.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
            entry.Entity.CreatedBy = _username;
        }
    }
    return base.SaveChanges();
}
```

how can i pass my identity variable to my constructor of the PNMP (context)

I'm using Ninject.MVC3 for binding the concrete class to the interface using :

```
kernel.Bind<ICustomerRepository>().To<CustomerRepository>();
```

Comment: If you want to pass the user identity to your context, why did you specify `DbContext,  new()` as generic type constraint.

Comment: Take a look at [this article](http://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=84). It shows an implementation of the repository and unit of work patterns for EF.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of injecting a `username` string primitive, just let your `DbContext` depend on a `IUserContext` abstraction. This allows you to simply register your services without having to resort to overriding any constructor arguments.

**UPDATE**

You can define an MVC specific implementation of `IUserContext` as follows:

```
public class MvcUserContxt : IUserContext
{
    public string UserName
    {
        get { return HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name; }
    }
}
```

And you can register it as follows:

```
Bind<IUserContext>().To<MvcUserContext>();
```

Comment: Steven, thanks for your information, but as I said. I'm stil learning and am a junior developer. With my question I think there is an issue that I didn't see en now don't know the answer. Being part of a MVC application passing in the username is only possible if knowing the lifetime of the context. Is the context created and disposed for every request over and over again for each individual user having their own context. With your answer, is there a place where I can find some extra information how to handle this?

Comment: Steven, I think I'm missing something. I have a codefirst Context called PNMP. You introduce the MvcUserContext and an Interface IUserContext. Is the IUserContext a self written interface (I assume yes). And where is my MvcUserContext placed. I have 3 projects. 1 with de cf Model, 1 with the repositories and 1 as being the MVC website. The PNMP context is placed in my repository project where no HttpContext is in scope. (or is it?)

Comment: @LuukKrijnen: The `IUserContext` has nothing to do with your EF `DbContext`. It is an abstraction that allows your application logic to get information about the current user. It is defined in a lower layer of the application, while the `MvcUserContext` will be defined in your web application. In other words, your `MvcUserContext` depends on the `HttpContext`, but the `IUserContext` doesn't.

Comment: However, instead of abusing your `DbContext` by overriding the `SaveChanges`, you might be better of by implementing this behavior in a decorator that you wrap around your business operations. Take a look at [this article](http://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=91). However, please note that this is advanced shizzle, so you might have som trouble grasping it.

Comment: Steven, thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I sure am going to read some of je blogarticles!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18518/discussion-between-luuk-krijnen-and-steven)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `WithConstructorParameter`:

```
kernel.Bind<IInterface>()
    .To<ConcreteClass>()
     .WithConstructorParameter("name", value);
```

However, I urge you *not* to use repositories to abstract away DbContext. It serves no real purpose. If you want to unit test your classes and your database is not trivial, you'll end up spending lots of time creating mock repositories - for no reason, just unit test with a snapshot of the database.

Microsoft did a very fine job abstracting away the database with DbContext, no need to abstract their abstraction.